# How to stop Elixir from interpreting \n as newline in docstring?

Tags: elixir

I am writing a docstring for a function, and in the examples section I want to show how it interacts with newlines. Example:

```
defmodule FooModule do
  @doc """
  Checks whether input is a newline symbol.

  ## Examples
      > newline? "\n"
      true
      > newline? "abc"
      false
  """
  def newline?("\n") do true end
  def newline?(input) when is_binary(input) do false end
end
```

This is how it looks in iex:

```
iex(31)> h FooModule.newline?

                              def newline?(input)                               

Checks whether input is a newline symbol.

Examples

┃ > newline? "

"

┃ true
┃ > newline? "abc"
┃ false
```

How do I fix that? Is there an alternative to **raw strings** in elixir? In Python I can write `foo = r"C:\Program Files\new program"`, and it will contain slashes and symbol n.

Comment: If you change > to iex> , you will be able to use doctest on your module. http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.DocTest.html

Answer (score 4):

Try using [sigil_S/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_S/2):

```
 @doc ~S"""
  \n will appear literally
  """
```

> Handles the sigil ~S.
>
> It simply returns a string without escaping characters and without interpolations.

Comment: Of course the other option is to use double backslash "\\n" :)